# Python's any() function on a list of lists gives weird outputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, any

Given a `list` of `list`s named `a`, I got the following outputs on exploration of the `any()` function. It would be great if I could get some help in understanding the logic behind these outputs. Why are some outputs `True` and some `False`, even though all should be `True`?

```py
a = [[1,2,3], [0,3,6], 5, [4,5,7], [0,1,2]]

print(any(a) in [0,3,4,[5],100])
print(any(a) in [1,2,3,4,5])     # Gives True
print(any(a) in [4,5,7,6])       # Gives False
print(any(a) in [0,1,2,4])       # Gives True
print(any(a) in [5])             # Gives False
```

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong. You are first computing `any(a)` (which is `True`) then check if `True` is in your target list. The reason it *sometimes* returns `True` is the fact that `int(True)` is equal to `1`, so it only prints `True` if your target list contains a `1`.

Try this, for example:

```
print(any(x in [4,5,7,6] for x in a))     # Should print True
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not the functioning of `any` but instead the functioning of **`in`** operator in python.

Basically `in` works in the following way :-

```py
for i in iterable:
    if i == value:
        return True
else:
    return False
```

Now if you apply this logic manually over one of your conditions that return `True`, you can find the element which causes this peculiar behaviour:-

```py
for i in [1,2,3,4,5]:
    if i == True: # Since any(a) is True
        print(i)
```

and the output this produces is :-

```
1
```

Thus, one thing which you can infer from this is that the integer `1` represents the boolean `True` also, which you can confirm by checking in the interactive shell :-

[image: Boolean Check]

Thus, you can observe that in python the integers `0` and `1` represent the booleans `False` and `True` respectively, too.

Therefore, now you can understand why your code executes in a peculiar way, like this...

```py
a = [[1,2,3], [0,3,6], 5, [4,5,7], [0,1,2]]

print(any(a) in [0,3,4,[5],100]) # Will give False because 1 is NOT present
print(any(a) in [1,2,3,4,5])     # Gives True because 1 is present
print(any(a) in [4,5,7,6])       # Gives False because 1 is NOT present
print(any(a) in [0,1,2,4])       # Gives True because 1 is present
print(any(a) in [5])             # Gives False because 1 is NOT present
```